# "deploy does not exist" error in jboss 7

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

I create a project using pure MVC and run in jboss server 7.1. And then in the console show the following error. I can't find how to solve it.Anyone can help, Thanks!

In the console,

```
16:34:55,562 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001:
Failed to start service jboss.server.deployment.scanner.JBossToolsScanner1: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.deployment.scanner.JBossToolsScanner1: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS015053: 
D:\all workspace\jpa workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_7.1_Runtime_Server1373648785140\deploy does not exist
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerService.start(DeploymentScannerService.java:165)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS015053: D:\all workspace\jpa workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_7.1_Runtime_Server1373648785140\deploy does not exist
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.<init>(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:171)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerService.start(DeploymentScannerService.java:151)
... 5 more
```